# input inside col-xs does not work on tablet and smartphone

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

input inside `col-xs-12` does not work on tablet and smartphone.

```
  <form role="form">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Input XS</label>
          <input type="text">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Input MD</label>
          <input type="text">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

[This is a plunker example.](https://plnkr.co/edit/TeMGjr9KHS9HwJy5x1GM?p=preview)

I can input text in `Input MD` but can not input any text in `Input XS` on my tablet and smartphone. But both `Input MD` and `Input XS` works on my PC.

Why `Input XS` does not work on tablet and smartphone?

Comment: Did u solve the question?

Comment: You can use Input SM for tablet sizes... I think input XS only worked in mobile devices....  Check this.. https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Bootstrap 3, elements with col-xs-* have CSS float property. You should provide all grid elements with col-xs-* to have proper floating elements.

```
  <form role="form">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Input XS</label>
          <input type="text">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Input MD</label>
          <input type="text">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

very easy, you should add clearfix div; you can't click your textbox because it is under the div `col-md-12` . try this:

```
<form role="form">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Input XS</label>
            <input type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Input MD</label>
            <input type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have already accepted another answer, but this also worked.

Comment: @N.F. xD, yeah, best luck for you. if you want both col-md-12 and col-xs-12, just use  col-xs-12, it is enough, it include col-md-12

Answer (score 0):

You can use Input SM for tablet sizes...

I think input XS only worked in mobile devices.... Check below link.. [w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp)

Comment: you need to display one input for MD size, one for XS size and other one for SM. Am i right ?